# Oracle Hibernate configuration to resolve connection refused error

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Tried to use hibernate for oracle and ended up with connection refused error.
ORA -12516

Following options were tried:

1. set the connection pool
2. Used c3p0 third party for setting up connection pool.
3. Changed ora settings to increase the job queue process.

Is there any better analysis or solution available to this ?

Comment: Did you manage to connect to the DB via sql*plus?

Comment: yes i was able to connect .....i checked if oracle reached the maximum process limit. the process was just 29 and i also restarted the oracle db. Is there any other setting specific to hibernate which needs to be set

Comment: Connecting via SQL*Plus is nice, but a better test is whether you can connect through JDBC using that same URL you are giving HIbernate.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after changing the job queue process to 500. Each time the app run it went to 45 and this has caused the issue.